# Simple application of De Morgan's law

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This should be a simple application of De Morgan's law but I am having doubts.

I am trying to compute $\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{k} \bigcap_{j=1}^{n} F_{i,j} \right)^{c}$ and I think it is $\bigcap_{i=1}^{k} \bigcup_{j=1}^{n} F_{i,j}^{c} $.

Is this true?

Comment: That's quite right. Why are you having doubts about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. It can be proved in this way. Let $D_i=\bigcap_{j=1}^{n} F_{i,j}$. Then
$$
\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{k} \bigcap_{j=1}^{n} F_{i,j} \right)^{c}=\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{k} D_i \right)^{c}=\bigcap_{i=1}^{k} D_i ^{c}=\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^{n} F_{i,j}\right)^c=\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}\bigcup_{j=1}^{n} F_{i,j}^c
$$